# Linking between a navigation list and headings

Tags: html

I'm having trouble linking from some `nav` lists to some `h2` headings.

When I click the navigation bar in my document, I want it to jump down to the correct heading in the page.  Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Wisconsin Colleges and Universities</title>
    <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
    <link href="hestyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <base href="url" target="collegeWin"/>
  </head>

   <body>

      <header>
         <img src="highered.jpg" alt="Higher Education" />
      </header>

      <section> 

         <h1>Wisconsin Colleges and Universities</h1>

         <nav>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#private">Private Colleges and Universities</a></li>
               <li><a href="#technical">Technical College System</a></li>
               <li><a>University of Wisconsin System</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>

         <h2 id="private">Private Colleges and Universities</h2>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.alverno.edu">Alverno College</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
            <li><a href="http://www.wlc.edu">Wisconsin Lutheran College</a></li>
         </ul>

         <h2 id="technical">Technical College System</h2>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.blackhawk.edu">Blackhawk Technical College</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
            <li><a href="http://www.witc.edu">Wisconsin Indianhead Technical College</a></li>
         </ul>

         <h2 id="public">University of Wisconsin System</h2>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.uwgb.edu">UW-Green Bay</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
            <li><a href="http://www.uww.edu">UW-Whitewater</a></li>
         </ul>

         <footer>
            Higher &#9830; Ed: The Directory of Higher Education Opportunities
         </footer>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've put IDs on the `h2` headers and I try linking to them using `#`-prefixed fragment IDs. But for some reason I'm getting an error message stating "Cannot find. make sure the path or Internet address is correct."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a tag `base`. Remove it and it'll work. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Thanks! It did work!  One problem though.  The assignment asked me to create a base element to the document head to make all the links open by default in a new browser named collegeWin.  How do I successfully add this base without messing up the h2 and <nav> links?

Comment: Thierry, I got it.  In my base element in the document head, I changed the href="url"  to href="uwlist.htm"  and it works now :)

Comment: Thierry, sorry one more :)  I get the website url links to open up in another window via, <base href="" target="collegeWin"/> ,  but i'd like for all the links I click to open to that same window, so there aren't tons of new windows opened every link I click... any thoughts?

Comment: Have you try on different browsers ?

Comment: It worls in Chrome and Firefox but not IE

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <li><a href="#private" target="_self">Private Colleges and Universities</a></li>
 <li><a href="#technical" target="_self">Technical College System</a></li>
 <li><a href="#public" target="_self">University of Wisconsin System</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Didnt post html code above   try like this    <a href="#private" target="_self"